# I would like to kindly ask you could you check......?

Tags: politeness

I just want to know ***I would like to kindly ask you could you check......?*** could be a right structure for asking question?

regards

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Too complicated and long-winded is one thing, but it also doesn't sound right - I think it may be because you're repeating "you" twice, though I'm not sure. Try one of these:

> I would like to kindly ask you to check ...
>      Would you be so kind as to check ...
>      Could I ask you kindly to check ...
>      Could I kindly ask you to check ...
>      Could you please check ...

If, on the other hand, you want to ask whether somebody has already checked your file, you should go with:

> Would you be so kind as to tell me if/whether you have checked …
>    Could you please let me know if/whether you have checked …
>    I would [greatly] appreciate it if you could let me know if/whether/when you have checked …

Comment: But I want to know the third person has ckecked my file or not and lets me know,I don't want to ask for checking

Comment: Ooh. That's a completely different sentence then, with a meaning none of us got. Please check my updated answer :)

Comment: I'd class this as a request (for a favour) rather than a true question. You're expecting or at least hoping for willing compliance, not a mere 'Yes' (or 'No!').

Answer (score 12):

The problem with *to kindly ask* (apart from the split infinitive, which is cumbersome) is that it says that **you** are being kind when asking: you are asking kindly. It's usual to ask for someone else to be kind and do something.

> I would like to ask [you] could you kindly check......?

However, "I would like to ask" is meaningless, because you **are** asking. "I would like to ask" is more usefully followed by "but I won't". It's far more likely that the question would be

> Could you kindly check ... for me, please?

Comment: This ignores the 'please' usage: _kindly_ 8. please (often used to express impatience or formality): will you kindly behave yourself!. [Collins](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/kindly).

Comment: On the contrary, "could you kindly check...?" is implying "please".

Comment: Sorry;your 1st sentence.To quote [@tchrist](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/96162/is-it-correct-to-say-i-kindly-request-you-to): _We kindly request. . . .
We politely request. . . .
We humbly request. . . .
are all frequently seen in formal invitations and such. They are in the “expected” format. As with all language of courtesy, you should not get too worked up over what each word literally means in these frozen, fossilized forms. They have become formulaic, so it is “what people do” on such occasions._ I'd add 'We kindly ask ...'. Of course, OP's example does not use this formula.

Answer (score 1):

Too complicated and not idiomatically correct.

Try

> Would you be kind and check

or

> Could I ask you to kindly check...

After reading your comment, perhaps you mean

> May I ask you if you have checked my file?
>
> Would you be kind and tell me if you have already checked my file?

Comment: But I want to know the third person has ckecked my file or not and lets me know,I don't want to ask for checking

Answer (score 1):

The structure to asking a question usually goes as [verb] [object].

> Do you know the time?

If you would like to be polite, you'd say "please."

> Please check . . .

Comment: No. This (latter) is a request – almost a command – not a question. But then so are most of the examples here. The wrapping of the request in a question-like form of words is a commonly used hedging device. I'd not use a question mark when writing something like 'Could you open the window, please, Jill.'

Comment: A question may be a request.

Comment: 'Please check ...' certainly isn't a question. At [Proofthatblog](http://proofthatblog.com/2013/07/01/the-question-is-what-happened-to-the-question-mark/) is 'The biggest confusion will come in determining whether the thing you are asking is a direct question or a polite request. A polite request will not use a question mark but will use a period instead. · Will you please get the attorney’s signature on this pleading and return it to me. (Not really a question because you expect them to do it.) · May I suggest that you research flight times before you book the travel.'

Answer (score 1):

A futher suggestion:

- Would you be so kind to check ....