# Is it grammatically correct to start a sentence with the word "request", used as a verb?

Tags: grammaticality

For example: "Request you to respond as soon as possible."
I've encountered this sentence in a few e-mails (without subject words like "I" or "we").

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/96164/2085

Answer (score 5):

It's not grammatically correct, and comes across as a bit rude, but it can be argued that email is not formal communication most of the times it is used. It can also be argued that the "I" is implied, though in this case it is normal to use "I" and not simply imply it.

You will also see internet abbreviations that are not grammatically correct but are acceptable in the internet community. You can grit your teeth as you read that but what's acceptable in email would not be acceptable in formal writing.

Sneer if you will, but you won't change the communication medium it came in.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be used.

Instance: Requesting you to kindly consider.
In this case the request is in continuous form and hence can be used.

But only the verb form 'Request' would be harsh and as expressions are an integral part of communication it is better to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

It *could* be correct, on the basis of ellipsis. However, if the email is formal, it would not be desirable to use sentences more typical of an SMS conversation.

I would suggest the following, as it has a better flow:

> I politely request that you respond as soon as possible, please.

In my opinion, the above would be absolutely fine to use if you are of higher social standing than the recipient (e.g. boss --> employee), but if you are writing to someone above you, the following doesn't sound as rude and demanding:

> Could you please respond as soon as possible? [Perhaps insert the reason why here, or just "thank you".]

Answer (score 0):

Typically when verbs begin a sentence, they are addressing someone in the second person, such as "Go away!" (Unspoken "You") or "Leave this place!" ("[You] leave this place!")

Here, "Request" is a first person verb (it actually says "I Request") but drops the "I".  You would never say "Am happy you feel that way!"  This construction is just as awkward. As a previous poster said, it is impolite in formal communication.

That being said, I have been in the military or working for the military for 13 years, and this construction is pretty standard among that industry and used in almost every request.  If it is acceptable by the organization at large then it may be acceptable in their communication (as it is part of their own industry lingo). I would avoid it, though, especially if you are planning to address an audience with whom you are unfamiliar.

Answer (score 0):

We should never use *Request you to confirm the following details:*  Yet, people write it it formal emails. That is incorrect usage.

Instead, *We request you to confirm the following details:* is correct.

Comment: Hello, Sumana. Welcome to ELU, but please be aware that it is not a discussion forum. 'Answers' are expected to be accompanied by reasonable research; unsupported answer come across as (and may merely be) personal opinion.