# I'm requested to send me

Tags: grammar

Is it correct to say "I'm requested to send me the new invoice"?

What about this:
"I'm requested you to be there on time"

Comment: This question would receive a better answer at ell.stackexchange.com, a site that is devoted to the needs of people who are learning English.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/96164/2085

Answer (score 2):

"I'm requested" is passive: it means "Somebody has requested me". This does not appear to be what you intend to say.

Comment: Thank you guys for your nice conclusion. Honestly, I saw some where that somebody have used "I'm requested..." instead of "I want to ...". Because of that, I asked this question.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not. You are saying "I am requested to send me the new invoice." First, "I am" is present tense, while "requested" is past... the way you say it here, it's like you are saying, " I have been asked to send myself the new invoice." Which doesn't make a whole lot of sense. How I would say what I think you're trying to say is, "I made a request for them to send me the new invoice."
Most times you can't really be "requested". "I'm requesting" or "I have requested" are the proper ways to say what I think you're trying to say. Hope this helps.

Comment: While I agree with your conclusion, your analysis is wrong. "I am requested" is simply present passive: there's nothing past about it.

Answer (score 0):

Although the first is grammatically correct it means "someone has told me to send to myself the new invoice", which seems a little odd. The second is grammatically incorrect and the nearest I can guess us, "I'm requesting you to be there on time".