# Request to cross / Request crossing

Tags: differences, prepositions

In aviation radiovoice it is common to say 1) "Request to cross CTR (controllzone)", but an english native explained to me that 2) "Request crossing CTR" sounds more correct to him but he couldn't explain why.

Since that day I wonder if he's correct and what's the difference between these two sayings (the same as stop doing /stop to do?)..?

Thx for help

Comment: This is what's known as *jargon*, specialized language used by a trade or profession. Normal grammatical and syntactical rules do not apply.

Comment: You need to check this with an [Air Traffic Control](http://www.nats.aero/) operator.

Comment: "Request to cross" is shorthand for "I hereby request authorization to cross ...".  It would not make sense to say "I hereby request authorization crossing ...".

Comment: Compare "request to come aboard".

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/96164/2085

Answer (score 2):

1) "Request to cross CTR"

In this case 'request' is a noun and the full sentence would be:
"This is a request to cross the CTR."

2) "Request crossing CTR"

Here 'request' is a verb and, crucially, 'crossing CTR' is the name of an activity where 'crossing' is a gerund.  The sentence in full might be:
"I request the procedure called 'crossing CTR'. "

This last does make sense because such a crossing will be carefully monitored by ATC for safety reasons. It is therefore a co-ordinated procedure that involves both pilot and ATC.

Answer (score -1):

Actually is "requesting Cross." Example:

> "Copter 2340W requesting fuel (Delta/Brookwood departure)."

Comment: Your example doesn't include the phrase "requesting Cross." Can you explain how that phrase fits in with the example?