# Is "for" wrong in a direct request?

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions

I was drafting a mail to the IT Department of my university when this question hit me. Do I need *for*? If I don't actually need it, is it really wrong?

1. I request the necessary changes to be made
2. I request for the necessary changes to be made

Comment: Related and possible duplicate of http://english.stackexchange.com/a/96164/2085

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to state is that we are talking about *request* as a verb.

Overall *request for* is the most used collocation in books. [Consider this ngram.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=request+for+*%2C+request+*&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Crequest%20for%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Brequest%20for%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brequest%20for%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brequest%20for%20an%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brequest%20for%20information%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brequest%20for%20his%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brequest%20for%20permission%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brequest%20for%20help%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brequest%20for%20assistance%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brequest%20for%20such%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brequest%20for%20more%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Crequest%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Brequest%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brequest%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brequest%20that%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brequest%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brequest%20was%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brequest%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brequest%20you%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brequest%20and%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brequest%20from%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brequest%20is%3B%2Cc0) Of course, these are primarily uses of *request* as a noun, where the collocation with *for* is very common.

If you use *request as a verb* then you shouldn't use *for.* The collocation with *for* is very unusual for the verb form as [this ngram shows](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=request_VERB+for+*%2C+request_VERB+*&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Crequest_VERB%20for%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Brequest_VERB%20for%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brequest_VERB%20for%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brequest_VERB%20for%20them%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brequest_VERB%20for%20him%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brequest_VERB%20for%20his%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brequest_VERB%20for%20your%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brequest_VERB%20for%20himself%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brequest_VERB%20for%20publication%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brequest_VERB%20for%20an%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brequest_VERB%20for%20my%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Crequest_VERB%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Brequest_VERB%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brequest_VERB%20that%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brequest_VERB%20you%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brequest_VERB%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brequest_VERB%20your%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brequest_VERB%20him%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brequest_VERB%20his%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brequest_VERB%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brequest_VERB%20an%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brequest_VERB%20it%3B%2Cc0).

As WS2 has pointed out in the verb usage the *for* is implied.

> *request VERB* Politely or formally ask for - [ODO](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/request)

Comment: I think *your* NGram is highly misleading. Almost every single one of the hits for *request **for*** will be ***noun*** contexts. And when I force the verb context by searching for ***he requested for***, it seems most hits are probably contexts like *[the favour that] he requested for [himself]*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers of course it does, I pointed that out in the next sentence and gave the verb request ngram as well.

Comment: oic. I misunderstood your first sentence, and then didn't read the rest properly. But it seems OP is only asking about the ***verb*** context, so arguably your point about *a **request for** help* being a perfectly natural ***noun*** usage should really only have been posted as a comment (to the question itself, or to @WS2's answer, which seems fine to me).

Comment: @FumbleFingers rereading it I agree, that it's not as clear as I intended it. You're right about it unclearly addressing another answer. I'll clear it up.

Answer (score 1):

With *request*, one never uses *for*. One requests someone to come to see you. One requests a cup of tea.

As regards *ask* (unless you are from the Tyne or Wear district of north-east England) **omit the *for***.

If, however, you are asking for an object (even abstract one) then use *for*. E.g. if you are thirsty ask *for* a drink. But ask someone to make you a drink.

You could ask someone *for their thoughts*. But you would *ask them to think about the matter*.

In other words if the verb *ask* precedes an infinitive of a verb, you drop the *for* - (unless you are a Geordie).

**But you **NEVER *request for***

Is that understandable?

Comment: 'Request' means the same as 'ask for' - we don't say 'request for'.

Comment: None of the versions of this question mention *ask* at all. They all use *request.*

Comment: My apologies @Andrew Leach, for misreading the question. I think it was just that so many people confuse when to say *ask* and when *ask for*, that I mentally identified it in that way. I have substantially edited my answer.

Comment: You could always use "I request that the necessary changes be made". A bit more old fashioned perhaps but then I'm getting on a bit.